# How to check if a JFrame is in existence?

Tags: java, jframe

I am making an application where I need to have a Preferences JFrame which can open another JFrame for further preferences of a certain type. Though I do not want the further preferences JFrame to be able to have more than one instance open at the same time.

I have tried using the `.isActive()` method but that always no matter what happens reports that the variable used to make the new instance of the JFrame is equal to `null`, which it has been initially set to when it was initialised.

So what is the best way of actually checking if a certain JFrame already has an instance in existence? Is it to get it to write to a variable when it launches and when it quits? If so, how would you get it to write to a variable when someone pressed the `x` button, and what if it crashed and closed not through the standard means?

Or is there another way of doing it like getting the `isActive()` method to work or another method that would do better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you *should* do is to make the JFrame a modal JDialog. Instead of opening a JFrame, you open a [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog(java.awt.Dialog,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)). You pass the other settings window as the `parent` and pass `true` for `modal`. This will prevent *any* action in the other settings window as long as this modal dialog is open.

Thats what a lot/almost every program uses. Have you ever noticed that, when you open a settings window and try to click on the main window, the settings window pops back on top and blinks for a second? Thats what the modal dialog does.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just avoid creating a new JFrame at all? Just make one earlier in your execution and make it visible when you need it and hide it when you temporarily don't need it anymore. Trying to make an already visible JFrame visible or hide a hidden JFrame shouldn't do anything.

Comment: If you can do what you want with a JDialog tkausl's answer is a better idea.

Comment: I have thought about that, and that will be last resort. But it's because depending on which option they want to expand, a slightly different thing of preferences will come up, so it would have to refresh them, and then make it visible which might not be completely clean, but maybe I will go with that.

Comment: If you could do this with mutable components, all the refreshing would take would be a call to JFrame's repaint method (and pack if scaling would be needed too).